# php form send to email inputted in email field

Tags: php

I would like my simple php mailer form, to maintain sending me the filled out form; but also I would like to send them a confirmation message based on their inputted email address field - wondering if it's possible to send to email inserted in the form.

**Eg: User fills out email address in the field as asked; this is where custom confirmation will be sent upon submit (along with form submission to me)**

Note: // Same confirmation will be sent to every form user. I simply would like to write; with PHP - send this message to the email address inserted by current user in email field.

Updated:

---

I currently have the form submitting at my email:

```
$emailAddress = 'myemail@myemail.com';
```

I'm getting the fields with:

```
Email:  '.$_POST['email'].'<br />
```

How do I edit it to send to the user inputted 'email as their email address' -- and spit out the generic message with it?

---

Recent attempt:

```
$emailAddress = 'myemail@myemail.com';
$to      = $_POST['email'];
$message = 'Thank you for submitting the form on our website.!';
```

Form submits as normally; but doesn't send confirmation to '`$to      = $_POST['email'];`'

Any pointers?

---

Complete code:

```
<?php


$emailAddress = 'myemail@myemail.com';
$to      = $_POST['email'];
$message = 'Thank you for submitting the form on our website.!';

/* config end */


require "phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php";

session_name("fancyform");
session_start();    


foreach($_POST as $k=>$v)
{
    if(ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc'))
    $_POST[$k]=stripslashes($_POST[$k]);

    $_POST[$k]=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST[$k]));
}


$err = array();

if(!checkLen('name'))
    $err[]='The name field is too short or empty!';

if(!checkLen('email'))
    $err[]='The email field is too short or empty!';
else if(!checkEmail($_POST['email']))
    $err[]='Your email is not valid!';

/* if(!checkLen('phone'))
    $err[]='The phone field is too short or empty!'; */

/*if(!checkLen('subject'))
    $err[]='You have not selected a subject!';*/

/* if(!checkLen('message'))
    $err[]='The message field is too short or empty!';*/

if((int)$_POST['captcha'] != $_SESSION['expect'])
    $err[]='The captcha code is wrong!';


if(count($err))
{
    if($_POST['ajax'])
    {
        echo '-1';
    }

    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])
    {
        $_SESSION['errStr'] = implode('<br />',$err);
        $_SESSION['post']=$_POST;

        header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    }

    exit;
}


$msg=
'Name:  '.$_POST['name'].'<br />
Phone:  '.$_POST['phone'].'<br />
Email:  '.$_POST['email'].'<br />
IP: '.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'<br /><br />
Referred By:    '.$_POST['referer'].'<br /><br />
Message:<br /><br />

'.nl2br($_POST['message']).'

';


$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsMail();

$mail->AddReplyTo($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);
$mail->AddAddress($emailAddress);
$mail->SetFrom($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);
$mail->Subject = "A new Bridgetower.com Lead".mb_strtolower($_POST['subject'])." from ".$_POST['name']." | Via your contact form feedback";

$mail->MsgHTML($msg);

$mail->Send();


unset($_SESSION['post']);

if($_POST['ajax'])
{
    echo '1';
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['sent']=1;

    if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])
        header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

    exit;
}

function checkLen($str,$len=2)
{
    return isset($_POST[$str]) && mb_strlen(strip_tags($_POST[$str]),"utf-8") > $len;
}

function checkEmail($str)
{
    return preg_match("/^[\.A-z0-9_\-\+]+[@][A-z0-9_\-]+([.][A-z0-9_\-]+)+[A-z]{1,4}$/", $str);
}

?>
```

How could I output:

```
$to      = $_POST['email'];
$message = 'Thank you for submitting the form on our website.!';
```

Comment: Not a good idea to have a public script sending emails to a user inputted email.  Especially if the user controls the message.  Either way, spammers will attempt to send emails through it and will most likely get your web site IP blacklisted.

Comment: User will not control the messages -- it will be same confirmation per every form submission.

Comment: Okay, that is better.  As long as it doesn't contain anything else from the form.  I would still recommend using a captcha.  This is pretty easy to do, what have you tried?  How are you sending the form submission to your email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at PHPMailer. It's a pretty hand library for sending emails.

http://phpmailer.worxware.com

You can then just use GET or POST variables to send the email to the server

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can do this. It's just as straight forward as it sounds. I recommend using a mailer helper like phpmailer, but you do it with the php mail function as well.

```
//check the email is real
if (filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $to      = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = 'Thanks for filling out my form';
    $message = 'The message';
    $headers = 'From: me@mywebsite.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@mywebsite.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

straight outta the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Comment: Thanks @Bryan - this is close; I've updated my Question with current code, and still can't get the confirmation email sent

Comment: echo $_POST['email'] and see what is.

Comment: also please post a more complete chunk of code. Include the call to the mail function.

Comment: Done and Done! Updated Q

Comment: You're not trying to send anything to the posted email in your script... The only mail your sending is to $emailAddress, so of course you're not getting email anywhere else.

Comment: Thanks @Bryan, yeah, I realize. How could I output that to send?

Comment: copy the phpmailer part you already have and change the instance variables to be what you want. ie `$mail->addAddress($to);` `$mail->msgHtml($message);` and so on.

Comment: This worked; but killed the original functionality of form submitting to default email with form fields as well.

Comment: then you did it wrong. - you don't replace the current code, make a copy of the mail part and have 2 of them. One does what it originally did, the other sends to the user email.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the built-in PHP `mail()` function. You post a form to your PHP page, with HTML like so:

```
<form action="your_php_script.php" method="post">
E-mail:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="email" />
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

And `your_php_script.php` like so:

```
<?php
$to      = $_POST['email'];
$subject = 'Confirmation E-mail';
$message = 'Thank you for submitting the form on our website.';
$headers = 'From: donotreply@yoursite.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@yoursite.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php